# No more data to read from socket vender code 17410

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

No more data to read from socket `error 17410`

I have set oracle parameter `_optim_peek_user_binds = false`.
 
Also, I have set `server = SHARED` in `tnsnames.ora`

Still, the error is not solved.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked at the alert log and trace files to see if the DB process is terminating? If there is nothing there then check your Java/JDBC/driver setup.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the alert log and trace files present.

Comment: [About Monitoring Errors with Trace Files and the Alert Log](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/monitoring-the-database.html#GUID-29ECD5A0-118F-40FC-B54A-8B0D92E91314).

Comment: Can you please let me know what to do in the driver setup

Comment: @bned what driver also, what are you doing when you get this?

Comment: There was a version problem, its solved. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem trying to connect **from any user** to a database. I solved the error 17410 by going to my Oracle console, stopping and restarting my autonomous database.

Hope it helps.